# What bundler allows aggregating component dependencies (CSS/JS) in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webpack, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

Starting with the assumption that a monolithic CSS/JS file is bad (correct me if that is the way of the world now). Is there any module bundler for ASP.NET MVC 5 that lets you specify CSS & JS dependencies within each component and then uses those dependencies to build the best bundled files for each page (or combination of pages, user types, etc).

For me, this is all manual now. I see some JS/CSS only used by some roles, package them together and reference them if that role is active. It seems like in the PHP/Node world the bundlers often "see" the references inside the component templates as well as inside the JS/CSS libs themselves and bundles them so it all just works.

Is that a thing?

Comment: http://jamesknelson.com/which-build-system-should-i-use-for-my-javascript-app/

Comment: Yes, there are definitely lots of module bundlers, but the idea of building up those bundles based on dependencies expressed in the views/components, not so much. Here is one I just stumbled across.   https://github.com/Shazwazza/ClientDependency